# Given a solution of a second order non-homogeneous ODE, how to get all of its solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $x_1(t)$ is one solution of the equation
$$x''+a_1(t)x'+a_2(t)x=f(t),$$
how to get all solutions of it?

Assume $x_2(t)$ is another solution of the equation above.

I know if $f(t)=0$, it is a homogeneous equation, according to Abel's identity:
$$W(x_1, x_2)(t) = \begin{vmatrix}x_1(t) & x_2(t) \\ x_1'(t) & x_2'(t)\end{vmatrix} = W(x_1, x_2)(t_0) e^{-\int_{t_0}^t p(\eta) d\eta}$$
then $x_2(t)$ can be solved. But if $f(t)\ne 0$, I don't know how to do. And can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Any solution is necessarily of the type $x(t)=x_1(t)+y(t)$ where $y(t)$ is a solution corresponding to $f=0$. This is because $x(t)-x_1(t)$ solves the equation with $f=0$.

Comment: I know, but $x_1(t)$ is the solution of the nonhomogeneous equation, the Abel's identity isn't correct.

Comment: You are told that $x_1$ is a solution and you are asked to write all solutions using it, right? @YanPeng

Comment: @YanPeng Use Wronskian only for the homogeneous equation. Don't use it with $f$ on the right side.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So I don’t know how to do, I just know one solution of the nonhomogeneous equation, from this I don’t know how to get a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation.

Comment: @YanPeng I don't quite understand what you are saying. You clearly mentined that when $f=0$ you know how to get $x_2$. I am calling this this $x_2$  as $y$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I mean, if $f\ne 0$, I don't know how to get $x_2$, because I cannot use Wronskian.